# Composer autoload in Wordpress custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, composer-php, autoload

I'm developing a brand new Wordpress plugin and I would like to use Composer to autoload classes.

Here is the **plugin directory heriarchy**:

[image]

my **composer.json** content:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "G4S_ECommerce\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

In the directory where composer.json is, on **cmd**, I execute:

```
composer install -> this generates the vendor/composer folder and the vendore/autoload.php.

composer composer dumpautoload -o -> outputs "Generated optimized autoload files containing 0 classes"
```

In the main file **G4S_Ecommerce.php** I put the following line:

```
 require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';
```

In the same file I put

```
use G4S_Ecommerce\Includes\Ecommerce;

$starter = new Ecommerce();
```

but it leads me to a ***Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'G4S_Ecommerce\Includes\Ecommerce' not found***

Why the composer dumpautoload -o returns 0 classes? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First (it is not obvious from your files structure) you need to set a namespace for your `Ecommerce` class (i.e., `G4S_Ecommerce/Includes`)

Second, based on what you've declared in the autoload directive, composer is expecting to find the `G4S_Ecommerce` folder under the `src` folder, and in that folder you need to place your php class file with a name identical to the class name (i.e., `Ecommerce`).